# No sound when I use Audiotrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

Strange situation. I use AudioTrack but no sound is played....
My code for playing:

```
private class wPlaySound extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        float sampleRate = 8000;
        int sampleSizeInBytes = 2;
        int samplePerFrame = (int) sampleRate / (1000 / 20); // 20мс
        int frameSize = sampleSizeInBytes * samplePerFrame;
        int minBuf = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        Log.v("w201", "Buffer Size: " + minBuf);

        AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBuf * 100, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        at.setStereoVolume(1.0f,1.0f);
        at.play();
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i = i + frameSize) {
            Log.v("w201","write: "+at.write(data, i, frameSize));
        }
        at.flush();
        at.stop();
        at.release();
    }
}
```

I can understand if I hear a noise or some not correct sound. But I don't hear anything....

EDIT:
How I got data. It's not perfect and will not work on all of devices but it's work on my phone and tablet

```
private class wRecordSound extends Thread {
    public boolean stop = false;

    public wRecordSound() {
        position = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int freq = 8000;
        int sampleSizeInBytes = 2;
        int samplePerFrame = (int) freq / (1000 / 20); // 20мс
        int frameSize = sampleSizeInBytes * samplePerFrame;

        final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        final AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
        if (audioRecord.getState()!=AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            Log.v("w201","audio recorder not init" );
            return;
        }
        try {
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            while (!stop) {


                position += audioRecord.read(data, position, frameSize);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        audioRecord.stop();
        audioRecord.release();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:** I found that it start to play sound only after I called method stop of AudioTrack. But what me to do if I need to play each frame?

```
_loop_
_receive_frame_
at.play
at.write(_one frame_)
at.stop
```

Comment: sound that I take from MIC. I checked it has some data. Even if it wrong or I play it with wrong speed - I should hear some noise. But 100% silent
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Do you see any log data from AudioTrack, is it silent or does it output write: userSize?

Comment: @KristianMartinsen I'm having a similar problem with `ExoPlayer`, the first time it plays fine, after that each I get `[AudioTrack] write userSize 2400`

Answer (score 0):

The code below:

```
at.play();
at.write(data, i, frameSize));
at.flush();
at.stop();
at.release();
```

would not play correctly. Writes only blocks until data is written to the buffer, not until it is done playing. You need to remove "flush", it should not be called on playing buffer anyway. See below:

```
at.play();
at.write(data, i, frameSize));
at.stop();
at.release();
```

This way stop will finish playback. But if you need immediate stop, you should do:

```
at.pause();
at.flush();
```